# Does every belongs_to has_many association need nested routes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes, associations

This is a fairly basic question but I haven't been able to find concrete answers online.  Every `has_many belongs_to` does not need nested routes correct?  Should you only use nested routes when you're looking for URLs of the form `class/:id/class/:id`?

For example, let's say I have two classes `Profile` and `Post`.

models/profile

```
has_many :posts
```

models/post

```
belongs_to :profile
```

There's no separate `post` URL, the `posts` are displayed in `profiles/show`.  Should the `post` routes (in this case it would be only actions like :new, :create, and :destroy) be nested inside the `:profiles` resource? The rails guide states that resources should not be nested more than one level deep and there are often times.  Making nested resources for every association seems like it would violate this rule very quickly.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have no use for `/profile/1/posts` or `/profile/1/posts/1` you do not need the nested routes. However, I urge you to rethink, nested routes make for clean RESTful APIs

For example, the neat little nested route:

```
resources :profile, :shallow => true do
  resources :posts
end
```

will give you all these realy useful routes:

```
   profile_posts GET    /profile/:profile_id/posts(.:format)     posts#index
                 POST   /profile/:profile_id/posts(.:format)     posts#create
new_profile_post GET    /profile/:profile_id/posts/new(.:format) posts#new
       edit_post GET    /posts/:id/edit(.:format)                posts#edit
            post GET    /posts/:id(.:format)                     posts#show
                 PUT    /posts/:id(.:format)                     posts#update
                 DELETE /posts/:id(.:format)                     posts#destroy
   profile_index GET    /profile(.:format)                       profile#index
                 POST   /profile(.:format)                       profile#create
     new_profile GET    /profile/new(.:format)                   profile#new
    edit_profile GET    /profile/:id/edit(.:format)              profile#edit
         profile GET    /profile/:id(.:format)                   profile#show
                 PUT    /profile/:id(.:format)                   profile#update
                 DELETE /profile/:id(.:format)                   profile#destroy
```

This way you have to freedom to choose the nested route when necessary/useful, such as

```
GET /profile/:profile_id/posts/new(.:format) # create a new post for the given profile_id
GET /profile/:profile_id/posts(.:format) # return all posts for the given profile_id
```

and use the shallow routes where the nested routes are not necessary

Comment: So it's best practice to make posts a nested resource of profiles?

Comment: I do think so. Please reread the answer, I've added some more info. Especially about `:shallow => true`. But in the end it realy depends on what you want. If you are 100% sure that you never want to use the shallow routes, then of course, leave them out.

Answer (score 1):

If you read Section 2.7 of the Ruby on Rails Guide it states that:

> Nested routes allow you to capture this relationship in your routing.

See - http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default for reference.

Further to this you may want to perform particular operations on a class i.e. `user` which has `create`, `edit` etc ... every user is associated with a particular booking. That means that whenever you do anything to a user, you really are doing something to an user/booking. Because this is associated with this.

RESTful routes is a clean way of setting your application and making good use of unified resource identifiers. An example of this would be identifying a particular user such as /users/1/bookings/3 this would show the first user.